# jq query where key is part of the data itself

Tags: json, key, jq

I have the following JSON data from an API call.....

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "meta": {
    "count": 3
  },
  "data": {
    "1030907370": {
      "client_language": "en",
      "last_battle_time": 1548555418,
      "account_id": 1030907370,
      "created_at": 1525288212,
      "updated_at": 1548557165,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 3906,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "aaa",
      "logout_at": 1548557161
    },
    "1020786770": {
      "client_language": "ja",
      "last_battle_time": 1548948444,
      "account_id": 1020786770,
      "created_at": 1465998341,
      "updated_at": 1548948547,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 4396,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "bbb",
      "logout_at": 1548948544
    },
    "1018984431": {
      "client_language": "en",
      "last_battle_time": 1548550089,
      "account_id": 1018984431,
      "created_at": 1456254986,
      "updated_at": 1548550089,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 1666,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "ccc",
      "logout_at": 1548550016
    }
  }
```

}

I would like to end up with something like .....

> “account_id”: 1030907370,   “global_rating”: 3906
>
> “account_id”: 1020786770,   “global_rating”: 3906
>
> “account_id”: 1018984431,   “global_rating”: 3906

The fact that the "account_id" value is used a unique key is something I have not come across in tutorials and I need help with a jq query that will do the job.
Tks!

Answer (score 1):

The key here to accessing the key names is to use `keys`, `keys_unsorted`, or `to_entries`, e.g.

```
.data
| to_entries[]
| "\"account_id\": \(.key): \"global_rating\": \(.value.global_rating)"
```

### JSON objects

If you wanted the output in the form of a stream of JSON objects:

```
| .data
| to_entries[]
| {account_id: .key} + (.value | {global_rating})
```

Comment: @TerryPurdon please mark this reply as the right one